# I try to understand what this element is from Labview

Tags: labview, learning

I am an absolute beginner about Labview. I don't want to stop in Tutorial Hell. That's why I try to pick it up by reading the project
[Labview Based Automatic Antenna Pattern Measurement and Gain Caluclation](https://www.scribd.com/document/74707569/Labview-Based-Automatic-Antenna-Pattern-Measurement-and-Gain-Caluclation).

[image: Unknowm item]

Can anyone tell me what this element is?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Concatenate Strings.  Below is an example.  You can stretch the object to input as many strings as you wish.

[image]